# How to stress test an apache server running on a linux box

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, fedora, stress-testing

There seems to be something taking our server off-line and we are having trouble tracing the cause, if it is down to load of a particular site or a script. It does seem to be Apache related.

Does anyone know of any Linux based tools we can run from another server to stress test our problematic server by seeing how many requests it takes before it goes down?

Thanks,
Shadi

Answer (score 32):

[ApacheBenchmark](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/programs/ab.html) works fairly well and is included in most (if not all) installs of Apache2.

```
 ab -n 1000 -c 5 -C "somecookie=rawr" http://ourwebsite.com/
```

Comment: Another good one: `ab -kc 10 -t 30 http://yourwebsite.com/`. It opens 10 connections, keeps them alive and makes as many concurrent requests as possible.

Answer (score 6):

You can also use Jakarta's Jmeter by Apache.

http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/index.html

I used this to stress test my server, and it is quite handy to run from outside computers and workstations with windows, highly configurable, and offers lots of pretty graphs and information especially on failures and what failures return and when the failures happen.

They also of course have Linux builds, but I have not used these.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look of different opensource tools that can help you to do load testing for webservers.

http://blog.carlosgomez.net/2010/03/web-load-testing-with-opensource-tools.html

Answer (score 0):

I know this is quite an old question :-).

However, the HTTP benchmarking tool [wkr](https://github.com/wg/wrk) is getting more and more popular these days.